# How to show that $f(x) = a^x$ is convex for $x \in \mathbb R$ using Jensen's inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, jensen-inequality

> A function is called convex downwards if the following inequality is satisfied:
>
> $$
> f(\lambda\cdot x_1 + (1-\lambda)\cdot x_2) \le \lambda\cdot f(x_1)+(1-\lambda)\cdot f(x_2), \; \text{where} \; \lambda \in [0,1]
> $$
>
> Show that $f(x) = a^x$ is convex for $\forall x \in \mathbb R$.

I've been recently solving a similar problem for $f(x) = ax^2 + bx +c$ by plugging arguments from the inequality into the function and expanding the terms. Then some of them vanished and I ended up with an easy to handle inequality.

But that didn't work in case $f(x) = a^x$. I've tried to apply a logarithm to both sides but that didn't simplify the inequality. I also tried dividing both sides by various powers of $a$ since it's always greater than $0$, also no luck.

So I need to somehow show that $a^{\lambda\cdot x_1+(1-\lambda)\cdot x_2} \le \lambda \cdot a^{x_1} + (1-\lambda)\cdot a^{x_2}$. How can i do it?

Comment: Why do you want to use Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @Adam Because the author of the problem asks so, the above is one of the problems on that inequality

Comment: Are you allowed to use weighted AM-GM?  (Do note that one of the common proofs of weighted AM-GM uses the convexity of $f(x) = e^x$ in the first place, so if that's the proof you used, that would be a circular argument.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler AM-GM can be proven in so many ways ... Some just using induction and that $x^2\geq0$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Since the problem is in a pre-calc section I'm free to use anything outside calculus. I know I could take second derivative, but not in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows immediately by the generalized AM-GM inequality:

$$u^{\lambda}v^{1-\lambda}\le \lambda u+(1-\lambda)v$$

for any $u,v>0$ and $\lambda\in[0,1].$